# When are all characteristic l representations liftable

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Suppose $G$ is a finite group, and $l$ is a prime, with $l$ coprime to the order $|G|$. (Thus we have complete reducibility for $G$ representations.) Is there a straightforward condition on $l$ which ensures that every irreducible representation of $G$ is liftable to a characteristic zero representation? (For instance, does the fact that we assume $l$ coprime to $|G|$ suffice?)

Comment: Do we need a new tag, characteristic-l? :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, $\operatorname{gcd}(l,|G|) = 1$ is sufficient.  This is an easy consequence of Brauer's modular representation theory.  See Serre's *Linear Representations of Finite Groups*, especially Chapter 18.

Comment: By the way, this reference is somehow overkill.  It would be nice to see a more direct argument in this much easier special case, e.g. starting with a version of Maschke's Theorem over $\mathbb{Z}_{\ell}[G]$.  My instruments predict a response coming in from a northwesternly direction...

Comment: Use the splitting of $A \rightarrow G \rightarrow B$ whenever the orders of $A$ and $B$ are relatively prime.  


Comment: One possible argument is via deformation theory, which will be very natural for some (but maybe not all).  Namely, given the irrep. $\rho$ in char. $\ell$, the obstructions to deformation are computed by ${\mathrm Ext}^2_{{\mathbb F}\_{\ell}}(\rho,\rho),$
and the mod $\ell$ tangent space to the deformation space is computed by ${\mathrm Ext}^1_{{\mathbb F}\_{\ell}}(\rho,\rho).$
Since both vanish when $\ell$ is prime to $|G|$, we see that
each irrep. $\rho$ mod $\ell$ lifts uniquely to an irrep. in char. 0.

Comment: Typo: in the above, the subscript ${\mathbb F}_{\ell}$ on the Ext spaces should be ${\mathbb F}_{\ell}[G]$.

Answer (score 7):

Another sufficient condition is that if $G$ is solvable, then for every prime $l$, every absolutely irreducible characteristic $l$ representation can be lifted to the complex numbers. In fact, solvability is not really necessary; $l$-solvability suffices. 
This is the Fong-Swan theorem.

---

Added later:  Since groups with order not divisible by $l$ are trivially $l$-solvable,
this sufficient condition includes, and is more general than the the condition stated by Pete L. Clark.